# Randomize the sf::st_point_surface() points placement within a polygon

Tags: postgis, r, sf

I have a dataset of our clients across the country (more than 100k rows). For each client, we know their county (polygon) but I would like to represent them with points instead.

I want to place the point representing each client randomly within their county so that the points don't overlap if many clients exist in one county.
I tried to use `sf::point_on_surface()` but all the points are put exactly at one place in each county.

I also tried to use `sf::st_sample()` to create a point for each client placed randomly in the their county but then I can't find a way to link the created point geometries back to their corresponding clients' attributes.

Is there a way to achieve this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make test data:

```
library(sf)
example(st_read) # creates "nc"

# use a subset of 20, drop a few columns:
regions = nc[10:20,1:5]

# create 20 clients with random CNTY_ID from the first 5 and a Z value:
clients = data.frame(CNTY_ID = sample(regions$CNTY_ID[1:5], 20, TRUE), Z=runif(20))
```

Now link the clients with the polygons - this matches on CNTY_ID because that exists in both data frames:

```
clients_regions = st_as_sf(merge(clients, regions))
```

Now sample one point from each polygon in the `clients_regions`. Without the `rep` (ie `st_sample(clients_regions, 1)`) you'd only get one point over the whole space:

```
pts = st_sample(clients_regions, rep(1, 20))
```

See where these points are:

```
plot(regions$geometry)
plot(pts, add=TRUE)
```

They are in the same order as the original clients data frame so we can make a spatial version of the clients data frame thus:

```
clients_pts = st_as_sf(data.frame(clients, geom=pts))
```

Which looks like this - its the clients data frame with a point geometry object:

```
  CNTY_ID         Z                   geometry
1    1840 0.6564693 POINT (-80.41501 36.49305)
2    1841 0.6647294 POINT (-80.28091 36.41598)
3    1840 0.3621561 POINT (-80.10025 36.51202)
```

and plotting them shows them to be in the first five regions:

```
> plot(regions$geom)
> plot(clients_pts$geom, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

You might need to convince yourself more, perhaps by doing an intersection back to the polygons to check.

At this point you no longer need `clients_regions` or `pts` so write this in a function that returns what you want.

Comment: Thank you @Spacedman
The keyword here is `They (points) are in the same order as the original clients data frame`.
This makes it possible to just `cbind` them together. Thank you for the insight!